# Is there a way to pull the first featured image in a loop and not all other featured images?

Tags: images

I have a loop that pulls the first three posts of a category. I want to use the featured image of the first post pulled for the background of the section the titles and links to these posts are displayed.

Is it possible to pull the first image without pulling all other images of posts that were pulled in the loop?

Here's the current loop:

```
 <?php
 $cinemasight_header_query = new WP_Query( array( 

 'category_name' => 'academy-awards',
 'posts_per_page' => 3 

 ) );

 if ($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :

 while($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :
 $cinemasight_header_query->the_post();?>

 <span class="Categories_Upper_Left">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
 </span>

 <?php endwhile;

 endif;

 wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

**EDIT (8/13/16, 8:56AM CST)**

Revised for most recent corrections.

```
<div class="Header_Section_Left"><span class="Category_Header_Title">ACADEMY AWARDS<br /></span><div id="Header_Upper_Left">
<?php
$cinemasight_header_query = new WP_Query( array( 

    'category_name' => 'academy-awards',
    'posts_per_page' => 3 

) );

if ($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :

while($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :
    $cinemasight_header_query->the_post();

if( 0 == $cinemasight_header_query->current_post ) :
  $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
  $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id );?>

<div class="Categories_Upper_Left" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>') ;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
</div>

  <?php continue;
endif;?>

<span class="Categories_Upper_Left">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
</span>

<?php endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could edit your question using the `edit` link above and post your loop code please?

Comment: you have a closing php tag that should not be there. Look after your while `$cinemasight_header_query->the_post();?>` should not have the `?>` also you need to add your _normal_ HTML to display the remaining 2 posts (without the image) between the `endif` and the `endwhile` just after the `continue`

Comment: Ok. I did tinkering, but I may still have everything in the wrong spot. Here's the test site I'm using to explore these changes:

http://anniversary.cinemasight.com/

I'll post my revised code. Currently, I'm only working on the portion in the upper left corner. (As a frame of reference, the logo I'm working on will go right in the middle of the four quadrants.

Comment: So, I just realized that I'm going about this the wrong way. I may have to go with two loops after all and that I may not have wanted this as a true background image. I may have to experiment a bit.

Comment: I see you got the code working, Great!  If you just want the image, you can use `get_post_thumbnail` as in my answer.  If you choose a different direction, just post a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/235365/99217)

You could check the index of the current loop and use `get_the_post_thumbnail` to get the image tag or `the_post_thumbnail` to echo it.

You can use the `$current_post` [property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) to get the current index and show only on first occurrence.  Here's the loop modified to achieve this.

```
<?php

$cinemasight_header_query = new WP_Query( array( 
 'category_name' => 'academy-awards',
 'posts_per_page' => 3 
) );

if ($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :

  while($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :

    $cinemasight_header_query->the_post(); 

    if( 0 == $cinemasight_header_query->current_post ) : // This will print on first index only
?>

<span class="Categories_Upper_Left">
  <span class="my-image-class"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
</span>

<?php 
  continue; // skip the rest of this loop because we got what we needed
endif; // End if for first index ?> 

<span class="Categories_Upper_Left">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
</span>

<?php 

  endwhile;

endif; // End loop

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

In my comment below, I used [get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) which returns the `<img>` tag without printing it.

[the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) will echo it's output. If you have custom image size, you can pass it as an argument with this function to retrieve it. Essentially, this function is a wrapper for `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and passes `post-thumbnail` as a default image size if none is given.

Chose which one suits you better

**EDIT**

For some reason I missed that you wanted to get the image to use as background. So you need only to fetch the `src` of the image and not the whole `<img>` tag

Just change the conditional for the first index like so

```
    if( 0 == $cinemasight_header_query->current_post ) : // This will print on first index only
      $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
      $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id ); ?>

<div class="my-image-class" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>') ;">
  <span> <?php echo the_title(); ?> </span>
</div>

    <?php 
      continue; // skip the rest of this loop because we got what we needed
    endif; // End if for first index ?>
```

[wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) will return an array of

- [0] : image url
- [1] : width
- [2] : height
- [3] : is_intermediate
- false if no image is found

and you can also pass the image size as second parameter to the function

Comment: When you say to "do your image tag formatting here," what am I putting in there? Because when I try to add spans, it doesn't work.

Comment: Well `get_the_post_thumbnail()` will give you your `<img>` tag. so if you wanted to wrap this around a `<span>` then you could try something like `echo '<span class="my-image-class">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</span>';` I'll update my answer with the code you put in your question.

Comment: I think this one may be answering my question, but I'm not 100% certain I've amended the code correctly. I edited my answer to reflect what you provided above (I can't figure out how to put code into comments.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest is with two separate loops. Run a first loop for just one item (thumbnail included) and then a second loop for the other items with `'offset' => 1` (thumbnails not included).

Comment: But that makes two queries (and all associated meta queries) rather than one.

Comment: Actually, I think the cleanest is how I described it in my answer, just check the current index and output if we are at first index. No double queries

Comment: @bynicolas yes, it's how I'd do it and you got my upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cinemasight_header_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'category_name' => 'academy-awards',
    'posts_per_page' => 3 
) );

if ($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :
    $counter = 0;
    while($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :
        $counter++;
        $cinemasight_header_query->the_post();

        if ( $counter == 1 ) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'image_size', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
            }
        } ?>

        <span class="Categories_Upper_Left">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
        </span>

    <?php endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();?>
```