# Is it possible to reverse the order of a list of posts pulled from a loop?

Tags: loop

I want to pull the three most recent posts from a specific category. I have the code to do that, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to reverse the order of these three posts when displaying/pulling the data?

Current Code:

```
 'category_name' => 'dvd-report',
 'posts_per_page' => 3,

 ) );

 if ($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :

 while($cinemasight_header_query->have_posts()) :
 $cinemasight_header_query->the_post();?>

 <span class="Categories_Lower_Right">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
 </span>

 <?php endwhile;

 endif;

 wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: do you still want the 3 most recent posts, but you just want to reverse their order?

Comment: Correct. I've updated to include my current loop code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are refering to the code of [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/235365/99217)

Taking the query from that answer

```
$args = array( 
  'category_name'  => 'your-category-slug',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$wpse_235685_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

you would then, to reverse the order of your results, need to modify the query `$posts` object, like so

```
$temp_posts = $wpse_235685_query->posts;  // store the posts to work with
$wpse_235685_query->posts = array(); // empty the $posts object
$wpse_235685_query->posts = array_reverse($temp_post); // set back the object to use new reverse order
```

of course this could be simplified by getting rid of the temporary variable like so

```
$wpse_235685_query->posts = array_reverse( $wpse_235685_query->posts );
```

This code should go between your `if( $wpse_235685_query->have_posts() ) :` and your `while( $wpse_235685_query->have_posts() ) :` so it doesn't run when the query returns an empty set.

Comment: Won't that retrieve the three oldest posts?

Comment: :facepalm @AndyMacaulay-Brook You are right, it will definitely do the opposite of what the op asked by getting the 3 oldest posts!  I'll update my answer!

Comment: Fixed the answer to reorder the results and not the entire query logic!

Comment: Ok. This worked. I used the simplified code (I prefer simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your array of the three most recent posts you can use `array_reverse()` ([php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)). This way you will still get the three most recent posts like you already do, but now they are in the reverse order.

```
$array_of_three_recent_posts = array_reverse($array_of_three_recent_posts);
```

Answer (score -1):

The args:

```
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'      => 3,
        'category_name'       => 'staff',   
        'order'               => 'ASC',
       'orderby'              => 'date'
    );
```

The query:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

      echo '<ul>';

       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();
           echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
       }

      echo '</ul>';
      /* Restore original Post Data */
      wp_reset_postdata();

   } else {
    // no posts found
  }
```

Comment: Won't that retrieve the three oldest posts?

Comment: @ Andy Macaulay-Brook You are correct. I failed to see past the 3 post. Lol, the wrong answer is the right answer! I'll fix my answer.